# Turning Conduits into Pipes

Tags: haskell

Does this look right to you? What are its shortcomings? Strengths?

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Pipe.Common
import Data.Conduit

c2p :: (Resource m, Monad m) => Conduit a m b -> Pipe a b m ()
c2p = do
  PreparedConduit push close <- lift $ runResourceT $ prepareConduit c
  loop push close
  where loop push close = do
          input <- await
          stepResult <- lift $ runResourceT $ push input
          case stepResult of
            Producing output -> do
              mapM_ yield output
              loop push close
            Finished _ output -> do
              mapM_ yield output
              lift $ runResourceT $ close
              return ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see three problems with this approach:

1) Calling `runResourceT` at each step releases all the scarse resources allocated by the original conduit. This is not what you want, since a conduit can depend on the availability of those resources until the point where it terminates.

2) You cannot call `close` after `push` returns `Finished`. This is [explicitly stated](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/conduit/0.1.1.1/doc/html/Data-Conduit.html#t%3aPreparedConduit) in the documentation of `PreparedConduit`.

3) You need to call `close` on the conduit when the upstream pipe terminates. Unfortunately, I think this is impossible to do with vanilla pipes. That's why I am currently experimenting with what I call "guarded pipes". You can find them [here](https://github.com/pcapriotti/pipes-extra), together with some other utilities ported over from conduits.

Using guarded pipes, you can write something like:

```
c2p :: Resource m => Conduit a m b -> Pipe a b (ResourceT m) ()
c2p c = do
  PreparedConduit push close <- lift $ prepareConduit c
  loop push close
  where
    loop push close = do
      input <- tryAwait
      case input of
        Nothing -> do
          output <- lift $ close
          mapM_ yield output
        Just input -> do
          stepResult <- lift $ push input
          case stepResult of
            Producing output -> do
              mapM_ yield output
              loop push close
            Finished _ output ->
              mapM_ yield output
```

You can try it, for example, with:

```
main = runResourceT . runPipe $
  fileProducer "sample.txt.gz" >+> c2p CZ.ungzip >+> fileConsumer "sample.txt"
```

where `fileProducer` and `fileConsumer` are also contained in the above pipes-extra package.

Comment: Nice! Producing a `Pipe a b (ResourceT m) ()` is what I tried at first, but the types didn't line up.